# storing data in db using AngularJS & laravel 5

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a setup like this.

My **html**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select a plate</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control m-t" id="plate_id"  ng-model="inspectionData.plate" ng-options="plate as (plate.serial_number) for plate in plates" required>
            <option value="">Please choose
              <span class="symbol required"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller looks like this.

```
$scope.storePlatesInspection = function() {

  PlatesInspectionFactory.inspectionUpdate($scope.inspectionData)
    .success(function(data)
    {
     $scope.ServerResponse = data;
     sweetAlert('Nailed it!', 'Your entered data was send to database', 'success');
     console.log($scope.inspectionData);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
        console.log($scope.inspectionData);
    });

};
```

my **service**

```
inspectionUpdate: function(inspectionData) {
    return $http({
        url: '/api/v1/plateinspection/',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param(inspectionData)
    });
}
```

All I want to take the selected data and send it back though the API and save it.

I am confused on how to catch all the objects being send from Angular

here is what I have been trying.

```
public function storePlateInspectionData(){
    $plate  =   Plate::find($request->input('plate_id'));
    $doc    =   Document::find($request->input('document_id'));
    $plate->documents()->attach($doc->id);
}
```

Should I use `Input::all()` or `request->all()` what are the best practices of doing this.

The `$request->input('plate_id)` is not working. Someone please help out.

This is what I get In my `console`

[image]

In this case I want the `id` which is `3` to save the data. How Can I achieve this?

update status code 500

[image]

Comment: On your `public function storePlateInspectionData()` you are not passing the request, so where does the `$request` comes from?  Your function should be something like this -> `public function storePlateInspectionData(Request $request)`

Comment: @FabioAntunes I pass the `$request` in the `constructor`. This is not the issue. When the `plate` object comes in I need to reach the `id` of it, which is `3`. So how can go about that? I have tried `$data = $request->all()` and than `$data['plate_id']` but is not working :(

Comment: first of all do a `var_dump($request->all());die;` on your `storePlateInspectionData` and check if it's receiving any data;

Comment: @FabioAntunes Not sure how to debug this. I am filling the from in my front-end how can I make sure the back-end receives it? I am not sure if `var_dump` will cut it.

Comment: If the var_dump is empty it's because you aren't receiving anything on your back end, just use the chrome dev tools and check your network pane

Comment: @FabioAntunes I gave it a try. Everything seems working. I get `200` status code on my API ( network pane). The var_dump is not showing anything on the console.log. Is there anyway to show if the `object` is actually reaching the method in the back-end?

Comment: Try to make request in chrome, and then inspect network panel with this request. And instead of var_dump better use laravel dd() function. 
And in your service no need in $.params, you can set just data object to send. And headers field is not required. Try method="POST".

Comment: @EchoUA.COM I have tried, either `dd` or `var_dump` are not appearing in the console. In the network panel I get status 500 ( which there is something wrong with my back-end).  I am confused now. How can I make request from chrome ( or what do you mean)?

Comment: Info show in network panel, not console. http://take.ms/Kd7Pv

Comment: @EchoUA.COM as I said I get status code `500`. Check the update above

Comment: @EchoUA.COM I can't seem to find `response` panel in my chrome dev tools. Any ideas?

Comment: 500 code means it's server error. Try to pass `Request $request` to your function. You store request to contructor, but use it as regular variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96492/discussion-between-user3641381-and-echoua-com).

Comment: Don't do a dd() that will throw an error on your angularjs,application,  because it tries to render javascript and HTML and makes it harder to debug